# Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined

Tags: meteor

Not sure where I'm going wrong here, please kindly assist.

Please see error below. Thank You

```js
////This is the client side JS////

if (Meteor.isClient) {
 Template.NewPerson.helpers({
  PersonSchema: function(){
    return schema.PersonSchema;
  }
});
}

////This is the schema////

Person = new Mongo.Collection('person');

Person.allow({
 insert: function(userID, doc){
  return !!userID;
 }
});

const PersonSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 FirstName: {
  type: String,
  label: "First Name"
 },
 LastName: {
  type: String,
  label: "Last Name" 
 },
 IdentityNumber: {
  type: Number,
  label: "Identity Number"
 },
 Address: {
  type: String,
  label: "Address"
 },
 PhoneNumber: {
  type: Number,
  label: "Phone Number"
 },
 User: {
  type: String,
  label: "User",
   autoValue: function(){
         return this.userId;
      },
      autoform: {
            type: "hidden", 
            label: false,
   },
  
  },
 
 //createdAt: {
 // type: Date,
 // label: "Created At",
 // autoValue: function(){
   
 // }
 // autoForm: {
 //  type: "hidden"
 //},
 
});

Person.attachSchema(PersonSchema);
Error:
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined
```

```css
////This is the error////

Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined
    at Object.quickFormContext (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?hash=5dbf44ff89f182bd8c2512330e170ef4d5bf9582:6713:34)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2994:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1653:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3046:66
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3687:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3045:27
    at Object.Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=65db8b6a8e3fca189b416de702967b1cb83d57d5:172:18)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?hash=5dbf44ff89f182bd8c2512330e170ef4d5bf9582:6662:23
    at wrappedArgFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2903:14)
    at .<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2616:26)
debug.js:41 Exception in defer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at .<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?hash=5dbf44ff89f182bd8c2512330e170ef4d5bf9582:6551:22)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1875:20
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:3687:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1873:29
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2214:12)
    at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1872:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:339:36)
    at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:229:10)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:604:11)
    at Blaze.View.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1885:22)
```

```html
////This is the client side HTML////

<template name="NewPerson">
     <div class="new-person-container">
   {{> quickForm collection=Person id="insertPersonForm" type="insert" class="new-person-form"}}
  </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: explain your problem more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the collection name when defining the `quickForm`:

```
<template name="NewPerson">
  <div class="new-person-container">
    {{> quickForm collection="Person" id="insertPersonForm" type="insert" class="new-person-form"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

In your helper file you also need:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
```

and possibly also:

```
import { Person } from 'pathToYourSchemaFile'
```

Comment: hi thank you for getting back to me, when I quote the collection, I get the folllowing error: Exception in template helper: Error: Person is not in the window scope

Comment: In addition to that I get a meteor.subscribe('person'); 
Uncaught ReferenceError: meteor is not defined error

Comment: It's capital M `Meteor.subscribe`. If `Person` is not defined then you need to import it's definition into your template helper file.

Comment: I actually tried that but to no avail, I'm sure I'm not defining it properly, I'm very new to this stuff so it's a huge learning curve for me

Comment: here is my actual helper file

Answer (score 0):

```
Person = new Mongo.Collection('person');

Person.allow({
    insert: function(userID, doc){
        return !!userID;
    }
});

Person.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    FirstName: {
        type: String,
        label: "First Name"
    },
    LastName: {
        type: String,
        label: "Last Name"  
    },
    IdentityNumber: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Identity Number"
    },
    Address: {
        type: String,
        label: "Address"
    },
    PhoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Phone Number"
    },
    User: {
        type: String,
        label: "User"
    },
}));

<template name="NewPerson">
     <div class="new-person-container">
     {{> quickForm collection=Person id="insertPersonForm" type="insert" class="new-person-form"}}
    </div>
 </template>
```

You don't need to pass schema into quick form once you attach it to collection.
It will determine what kind of data to populate based on collection schema.

Comment: I did try this, unfortunately though it didnt seem to solve the issue, anything else I could try?

Comment: share more information about error that function trows, and note that upper part (til template) should be placed in file outside client and server folder

Answer (score 0):

```js
Meteor.subscribe('person');

import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';


Template.Person.onCreated(function(){
 this.editMode = new ReactiveVar(false);
 // this.editMode = new ReactiveVar();
 // this.editMode.set(false);
});


Template.Person.helpers({
 updatePersonId: function() {
  return this._id;
 },
 editMode: function() {
  return Template.instance().editMode.get();
 }
});

Template.Person.events({
 'click .toggle-menu': function() {
  Meteor.call('toggleMenuItem', this._id, this.inMenu);
 },
 'click .fa-trash' : function() {
  Meteor.call('deletePerson', this._id);
 },
 'click .fa-pencil' : function(event, template) {
  template.editMode.set(!template.editMode.get());
 }
});
```